# Resize Problems

Tags: php, javascript

I am having 3 iframes acting as a textbox. And 3 divs in which the text written in iframe will appear it is working. I used drag Resize script also for Resizing Div. it is also working. The Problem is that when i am typing something in iframe, then I can't Resize div. Please Provide solution for it. I am stuck up with this problem. or give me Better Resize script.

You can see online.

The URL is this.
http://harleyyoung.com/custom_design.php?cid=Mg==&mid=52&id=Mg==

I am using the Resize script which i got from twihelix.com something like that

Comment: Please add links to any library you are using. Short code samples (of a demo, not your entire 300 line app) is also useful. Try to explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: Please give a more detailed description of what scripts you are using. Also, a link to a live example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> The Problem is that when i **am typing** something in iframe, then I **can't
>   Resize** div.

Then do one at a time.. Problem solved!